# Drop-down menu of suggestions in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Im far of an expert in this topic and Im trying to make a simple app (.exe) that allows to open a folder or PDF file inserting an sku of a product. I want to add a drop-down menu of suggestions that allows to complete the sku easier, also will be good to have an arrow to open a menu or something.

I see some options including a fixed list of suggestions, but there is some way to take for example folders name in a directory as possible suggestions that updates when you open the program?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the current code with no drop menu at all:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog

def open_pdf_in_folder(product_folder):
    pdf_folder_path = os.path.join(product_folder, "Production", "2-Documentation_PDFs")

    if os.path.exists(pdf_folder_path):
        for filename in os.listdir(pdf_folder_path):
            if filename.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
                pdf_path = os.path.join(pdf_folder_path, filename)
                try:
                    os.startfile(pdf_path)
                    result_label.config(text=f"Opened PDF at: {pdf_path}")
                except Exception as e:
                    result_label.config(text=f"Error opening PDF: {e}")
                return

    result_label.config(text="No PDF file found in the '2-Documentation_PDFs' folder.")

def open_folder_by_sku(product_folder):
    try:
        os.startfile(product_folder, '')
        result_label.config(text=f"Opened folder at: {product_folder}")
    except Exception as e:
        result_label.config(text=f"Error opening folder: {e}")

def open_explorer_with_sku():
    sku = sku_entry.get().strip()  # Get the SKU and remove leading/trailing spaces
    if not sku.startswith("MX-"):  # Check if SKU doesn't start with "MX-"
        sku = "MX-" + sku  # Add "MX-" prefix
    base_path = r'Z:\Product Data\Family Folders'

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path):
        if sku in dirs:
            product_folder = os.path.join(root, sku)
            open_pdf_in_folder(product_folder)
            return

    result_label.config(text=f"Folder for SKU {sku} not found.")

def open_explorer_with_sku2():
    sku = sku_entry.get().strip()  # Get the SKU and remove leading/trailing spaces
    if not sku.startswith("MX-"):  # Check if SKU doesn't start with "MX-"
        sku = "MX-" + sku  # Add "MX-" prefix
    base_path = r'Z:\Product Data\Family Folders'

    # Iterate through all subdirectories in the base path
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path):
        if sku in dirs:
            product_folder = os.path.join(root, sku)
            os.system(f'explorer "{product_folder}"')
            # open_pdf_in_folder(product_folder)
            return  # Stop searching after opening the PDF

    # If SKU is not found in any subdirectory
    result_label.config(text=f"Folder for SKU {sku} not found.")

def browse_folder():
    folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    sku_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    sku_entry.insert(0, os.path.basename(folder_path))
    
def clear_sku_entry():
    sku_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    result_label.config(text="")


app = tk.Tk()
app.title("Explorer")
#app.geometry("500x150") # Set a fixed width for the window

sku_label = ttk.Label(app, text="Enter SKU: MX-")
sku_entry = ttk.Entry(app)
pdf_button = ttk.Button(app, text="PDF", command=open_explorer_with_sku)
folder_button = ttk.Button(app, text="Folder", command=lambda: open_explorer_with_sku2())
result_label = ttk.Label(app, text="", width=50)  # Set a fixed width for the result label
clear_button = ttk.Button(app, text="Clear", command=clear_sku_entry)

clear_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
sku_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="E")
sku_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="W")
pdf_button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
folder_button.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
result_label.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
def getOptions() -> list:
        dirs = []
        for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
            if not os.path.isfile(file):
                continue
            
            if not file.upper().startswith('MX-'):
                continue
                
            dirs.append(file)
        return dirs
    
selectedOption = tk.StringVar()
options = getOptions()
drop = ttk.OptionMenu(app , selectedOption, options[0], *options) 
drop.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=2, pady=10)
```

`if not os.path.isfile(file):` checks if the file is a directory *( which will skip if true )*

`if not file.upper().startswith('MX-'):` checks if the file does not start with 'MX-' *( will skip the file if true )*

`os.getcwd()` is the current working directory but you can change this to basepath or wherever the files are

`selectedOption = tk.StringVar()` is a variable that represents the current item selected in the dropdown menu

You also could probably make an update button that will update the dropdown and I wasn't sure what you meant by

> an arrow to open a menu

but if you mean make a new window then you take the root aka `app` and use `toplevel` [toplevel guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-toplevel-widget/)

hope it helps :)

Comment: Why don't you call `getOptions()` once before creating the instance of `ttk.OptionMenu()`?  You are now scanning for files twice.

Comment: oh yeah Ig I didn't think about it and sometimes I reply with some amount of haste :/